# Reusable function from an external script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simplified Example:

```
// path/to/js/panel.js
$(function(){
    var hidePanel = function(){
        //hides the panel div
    };
});

// path/to/js/another-script.js
$(function(){
    hidePanel(); //out of scope MEGA-FAIL
});
```

As we speak, i have some functions/variables copy-pasted in 2 different files.
I was curious whether RequireJS would solve this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function itself just needs to be declared after jQuery is loaded *if* it needs jQuery, but it need not be declared on `document.ready`, just *executed* then.  The simplest way to do what you're after is:

```
// path/to/js/panel.js
function hidePanel() {
 //hides the panel div
}

// path/to/js/another-script.js
$(hidePanel);
```

This just passes your function to [`$()`, which schedules it run on `document.ready`, or immediately if the document is *already* ready](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

Comment: This will work in the simplified case scenario, but panel.js has various variables and i intend to use them in "another-script.js".
I think i 'll have to make a Panel() object in this case. :)

Comment: @fuSi0N - you can do that, or if you just need one copy: `var Panel = { hide: function() { ... }, otherFunc: function() { ... } };` would work.

Comment: I don't follow, can i use $(Panel);  and then use Panel.hide(); in "another-script.js"?

Comment: @fuSi0N - For the `another-script.js` if you want to run the hide function, it would be: `$(Panel.hide);` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// path/to/js/panel.js
$(function(){
    var hidePanel = function(){
        //hides the panel div
    };
});
```

With this code you create an an anonymous function. Anonymous functions don't pollute the global namespace. All variables (in this case *hidePanel*) declared in an anonymous function are not visible outside of the anonymous function.
Because of that the function is not available.

So you need to do a global function.
You can make that in different ways:

```
var hidePanel = function() {
});
```

---

```
function hidePanel() {
}
```

*P.S: I recommend that you learn the OO-Pattern for javascript :-)*
[Javascript Object-Oriented Programming | Part 1](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/oriented-programming-1)

Comment: I'm currently reading "Object-Oriented Javascript" book by Stoyan Stefanov and searching for ways to remove some complexity of an existing project.